# SQL - Insert Data from two tables into a third

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2005

There is Table1 with Product Information and Table 2 with Client information

```html
Table 1 (Product Information)
---------------
product | value
---------------
Product_A | 5
Product_B | 10



Table 2 (client Information)
----------------------------------------------------
ConsumerID | Purchase_product_A |  Purchase_product_B
----------------------------------------------------
1A | 3 | 4
2B | 2 | 3
```

I Need to have these informations in a third Table = Table 3

```html
Table 3
--------------------------------
ConsumerID | Frequency | product
---------------------------------
1A | 3 | Product_a
1A | 4 | Product_b
2B | 2 | Product_a
2B | 3 | Product_b
```

In table 3 , I need to have an overview of: ConsumerID, Frequency of purchases and the product. ConsumerID can have a separate Row for each product.

It is important to know that only SQL-Server-2005 is supported and each querie needs to beginn with a **Select**. Thanks for help.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpivot.  I like to use `apply` for this:

```
select u.*
from table2 t2 cross apply
     (select customer_id, 'A' as product, Frequency_purchase_product_A as frequency
      union all
      select customer_id, 'B' as product, Frequency_purchase_product_B as frequency
     ) u(customer_id, product, frequency);
```

I don't think the first table is necessary.

Comment: Hi Gordan, thanks for quick reply. I edited the tables to show the expected results. Do you still think that approach is working?

Comment: @Christian . . . You have to fill in the right product names, but yes, this should work.

Comment: @Gordan What happens now it is working for 'B' not not for 'A'. Meaning it selects alls Data from table2 but only for one product. Any ideas why ?

Comment: @Gordan. So it looks like ConsumerID was set as PrimaryKey and thats why it did not add informations for EACH product. Looks like this is solved now. I will varify.